# Slow Fresh Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, ubuntu-gnome, 18.10

I just installed a fresh Ubuntu (Cosmic Cuttlefish 18.10) into a fresh (empty) 1TB disk drive, and man... I can't even login into the user, typing takes some time to refresh on the screen, and sometimes the keys are inputed more than once (Figured this later)

When I finally could login typing the password 1 key by 1 key I noticed that this also happens with the mouse, it allows input for few milliseconds and then stops, so I need to lift he move and move it again it's not lag (I expected that eventually the pointer moves what I moved on the mouse later, but it didn't)

When trying to search for answers in Firefox doing a quick Ctrl+n (new Tab) the keys (input) would stick so It would open like 10-15 new tabs, the same for closing (Ctrl+W)

And searching (typing on the search bar) would do the same... "Slllllllllllow Ubunnnnnnnnnntu" so it was extremely impossible to even work with/on it.

It's a gaming PC so I figured it would be something about GNOME or nouveau drivers vs NVIDIA, it's a NVIDIA GTX 1060 (6GB)

I doubt it something else like memory leak, RAM or CPU processing, since it's a fresh install.

Any idea on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: You need to install Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in from another console with `ctrl` + `alt` + `F1`. It'll be the same user & password you created during install.  Is your input still lagged in a separate console?

Try looking for anything eating up memory or processors with `top` 
`ctrl` + `c` to exit

While you're there, do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

You can switch back to an xserver with `ctrl` + `alt` + `F7`

If that doesn't solve the problem, I would probably try the install again, just to see if something went wrong with that.